# Editable Forms Within Webpage?

Tags: pdf, input, zurb-foundation, embed, zurb-foundation-6

I'm working with Foundation 6 and trying to embed a PDF within a web page so someone can fill it out (editable via text input). I know you can make PDFs editable within Adobe Acrobat, but can I then embed that PDF and have it editable right there on the site (iframe?) without the user having to download it?

I'm sure there are plugins, but I'm not having any luck. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Your user will need a PDF viewer component which can properly deal with fillable PDF forms. In this situation, the normal fillable form will do it.

Comment: Got it. So they will always need something local themselves? No plugins available to provide that site-side?

Comment: Well, what you could do is find a tool which renders the PDF form as HTML5, for example, and then serve that form. However, I don't know what (if at all) exists.